# Point Source for electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I have a misleading picture of a point source in electromagnetic waves. The solution is the Green function. I can understand how a oscillating dipole generates a wave, but I can not see how a point source can generate a wave. Is it a point charge at the origin which at time zero vanishes? Thanks

Comment: In order to create an electromagnetic wave, the point source (point charge for example) has to be in motion. Is  this your situation?

Comment: It is just a Delta Dirac function, which explotes at x=0 and t=0.